# Не работает редирект в файле .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Не получается сделать 301 редирект в файле .htaccess на тот же файл и на ту же страницу, но с доп условиями.
Исходная страница c которой идет переадресация

```
https://site.ru/component/jr_vm/
```

Страница на которую должна быть переадресация

```
https://site.ru/component/jr_vm/?view=jrwmclient
```

Comment: Каков код самого редиректа в .htaccess ?

Comment: Вам нужен редирект с Гет запросами ?

Comment: Документация и примеры есть https://web-optimizator.com/301-redirekt-htaccess/, возможно блокировка из-за firewall

Comment: Код использую Redirect 301 /component/jr_vm/$ https://site.ru/component/jr_vm/?view=jrwmauthor